# Iterate a flux manually to get next element each time

Tags: project-reactor

I have defined a static Flux in a class and need to implement a method which will return its next element every time a call to that method is made. Is this possible? How can i achieve that?

Comment: [Flux.toIterable()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#toIterable--) function ? However, I wonder if Flux is the right tool to use in such case. What is your static Flux for ? Does it fetch data from an async datasource ?

Answer (score 1):

You *can*, but it's not ideal. If you really need something like this then it might signal your design isn't the best - or your task may not be brilliantly suited to a reactive environment.

A flux is (usually) push based rather than pull based, so you don't really have any control over when those elements are published. You can use backpressure via something like `limitRate()` to signal you want upstream to slow down, but that's not a guarantee. So it's not as simple as just calling a method on your `Flux` to say "hey, I want the next element, then stop until I tell you to go again."

If you really want to do it, you'll probably need to cache your Flux, then use `elementAt()` to get the element you need, maintaining an index as to what element you want to retrieve:

```
public class FluxTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(nextElement().block()); // 1
    System.out.println(nextElement().block()); // 2
    System.out.println(nextElement().block()); // 3
  }

  static Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.range(1, 10)
      .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(500))
      .cache();

  static int i;

  static Mono<Integer> nextElement() {
    return flux.elementAt(i++);
  }
}
```

...but this will obviously save all elements, indefinitely.

As an improvement, you may be able to implement some kind of high capacity circular buffer where your low mark can increment every time nextElement() is called - but I don't think there's support for that in a reactor operator directly (though I'm happy to be proven wrong!)

Comment: I was thinking this scenario like a producer-consumer pattern.  Actually this flux is a series of messages continuously retrieved from service bus, so I was thinking in that way. For now, my understanding is clear and not going by this way.

For above case, I implemented this as a Hot publisher.

    static Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.range(1, 4)
            .log().publish().autoConnect();

    static Mono<Integer> getFirstElement(){
        return flux.next();
    }